# Loop random posts and display odd and even based on two alternating meta values?

Tags: loop, order, meta-value

I have a CPT containing an ACF select field for gender values Male or Female. I need to to display 6 random posts AND they need to be ordered so the odd posts are female and the even posts are male.

They need to be random so that the same posts are not displayed each time the page is loaded.

What I have here works, however I can't work out how to display female, male, female, male etc. Can anyone help me?

Is there any way of switching between the two below in the query?

```
'meta_value' => 'Female',
'meta_value' => 'Male',
```

I have been searching and trying different things for hours and just cannot work it out. Can this even be done? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

What I have here works, however I can't work out how to display female, male, female, male etc. Can anyone help me?

```
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'rise_speakers',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    //'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id')), 
    'meta_key' => 'speaker-gender',
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<div class="speakers">';
    echo '<h1 class="entry-title">Keynote Speakers</h1>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  // Do Stuff
      echo '<div class="speaker">';               
          echo '<div class="speaker-thumbnail">';                 
            echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
          echo '</div>';                  
          the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
          echo '<p>';                 
          the_field( 'speaker-role' );
          echo '</p>';                
          echo '</div>';                  
endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
endif;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Did you manage to get exactly 3 male and 3 female at random??

Comment: No I didn't. Not in the same query.